# Flip elements to minimize the maximum consecutive elements together

Tags: arrays, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I have been given an array of 1's and 0's, and a number k. I am allowed to flip the elements of the array at most k times.(0 to 1 or 1 to 0).

I need to write an algorithm that flips the status of at most K elements so that the size of the maximum consecutive block of elements having the same element is minimised.

```
ex:

Array : 110001111 and k=2;
Solution is 2 , because: we can change the string to: 110101011, and the length of the maximum consecutive length is minimised to 2.

Array : 1001 k=1
Solution is 2, because: If we don't change the input string at all, the answer will be 2. It is the best value we can achieve under the given conditions.
```

Can some one provide me an approach to this problem?

Comment: For users looking to get this flagged, [please read a consensus view](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278808/1079354) on questions related to active contests.  Only judge this question based on its qualities as it's presented, not based on the moral code of another site.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to start with simplifying this problem:
We have a list of numbers, representing sequences of the same type:
`[a1,a2,a3...a_m]` such that their sum is `n`

The `k` operations are any of the following:

1. Replace `a_i` with [`a_i^1,1,a_i^2]`
2. Change `a_i` to `a_i-1` and `a_{i-1}` to `a_{i-1}+1`
3. Change `a_i` to `a_i+1` and `a_{i-1}` to `a_{i-1}-1`

But it's pretty clear that operation 2 and 3 are only better then operation 1 if `a_i<=2`, and unless there's only one element and the total length is 2, it is pointless to do anything in that case. So we can consider this to be the question of how to split the value, and in that case we do not care about the order of the `a_i`s

With `k` operations, what are the `k` operations you need to perform such that `max(a1,a2,...)` is minimal at the end

It is clear that if we do not flip a bit inside the maximal string, then we did not change the max. It is also clear that the order in which we flip the bits does not matter (e.g. it does not matter if we first flip bit number 7 and then bit number 4, or start with bit number 4 and then flip bit number 7). So we might as well decide to start with splitting the biggest consecutive block.

Biggest consecute block is of max length `n`, so we already found an `O(n^k)` algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

Let `f(i,len,k,state)` represent the smallest sequence up to index `i`, where `len` is the current sequence length, `k` is the number of flips so far and `state` is the state of `a[i]`.

Then:

```
if a[i] == 0:
  // starting a new sequence
  f(i, 1, k, 0) = min( f(i-1, len, k, 1) for all len)

  // adding to a sequence (len > 1)
  f(i, len, k, 0) = max( len, f(i-1, len-1, k, 0) )

  // starting a new sequence
  f(i, 1, k, 1) = min( f(i-1, len, k-1, 0) for all len)

  // adding to a sequence (len > 1)
  f(i, len, k, 1) = max( len, f(i-1, len-1, k-1, 1) )

if a[i] == 1:
  ...left as an exercise
```

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(a,i,len,k,state){
  // We cannot change the state of a[i] if k is zero
  if (k === 0 && a[i] != state)
    return Infinity;
    
  // The first element is a sequence of length 1
  if (i === 0)
    return 1;
    
  var oppositeState = state == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  
  if (a[i] == state){
    // Starting a new sequence
    if (len === 1){
      var best = Infinity;
      
      for (var l=1; l<i+1; l++)
        best = Math.min( best, f(a, i-1, l, k, oppositeState) );
  
      return best;
      
    // Adding to a sequence (len > 1)
    } else {
      return Math.max( len, f(a, i-1, len-1, k, state) );
    }

  // a[i] does not equal state
  } else if (k > 0) {
    // Starting a new sequence
    if (len === 1){
      var best = Infinity;
      
      for (var l=1; l<i+1; l++)
        best = Math.min( best, f(a, i-1, l, k-1, oppositeState) );
  
      return best;
      
    // Adding to a sequence (len > 1)
    } else {
      return Math.max( len, f(a, i-1, len-1, k-1, state) );
    } 

  // If k is zero, we cannot change the state of a[i]
  } else {
    return Infinity;
  }
}

function g(arr,k){
  var best = Infinity;
  
  for (var l=1; l<=2*arr.length; l++)
    best = Math.min(best, f(arr, arr.length-1, Math.ceil(l/2), k, l % 2));
    
  return best;
}

console.log( g('110001111',2) ); // 2

console.log( g('1001',1) ); // 2

console.log( g('111111',0) ); // 6
```

Comment: your code is showing wrong results for some cases. 111111 and k=0. answer should be 6 but your code gives 1.

Comment: @KaranNagpal Nope, my code returns the correct result, `6`, for `g('111111',0)`. I added your example at the end of my code.

Comment: Please don't delete your downvoted answer and repost it. It is considered as immoral to do that. If you have corrected the mistake, then wait until you get more votes on it.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thank you for your comment. I don't know about any mistake and I don't know why the answer was downvoted. I consider it immoral to downvote an answer without an explanation. Why don't you comment on the immorality of that kind of behaviour?

Comment: That has been discussed a lot on meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266836/why-does-stackexchange-website-just-dont-ban-down-voters-without-comment

Comment: @BhargavRao so has deleting and reposting after a downvote. The accepted answer here by someone with more than 200k rep, says that it's ok to do in isolated incidents. So, according to that, you are wrong https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56541/how-to-prevent-negative-comments-downvoted-being-deleted-by-re-posting-answers

Comment: I'm sorry, I stand corrected. Please do continue. I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: @BhargavRao just to be clear: I did infact delete and repost this answer because of the downvote. After the second answer was downvoted (I'm guessing by the same person, you can probably actually see that), I left this answer even with the annoying negative vote. This was quite some time ago.